# Include Entity Framework Core (Loop of data)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to include to the workstation list the connected devices. But i not only get the devices. I get as well the workstation. It's kind of a loop and unnecessary. How can I stop including the workstation again because this is as well including all kinds of others lists as well?

```
//returns to much
var workstations = this.context.TWorkstations 
   .Include(x => x.TDevices)
   .AsQueryable();

//crash -> see error msg
var workstations = this.context.TWorkstations 
   .Include(x => x.TDevices).ThenInclude(d => d.Select(y => y.Alias))
   .AsQueryable();

//crash -> see error msg
var workstations = this.context.TWorkstations 
   .Include(x => x.TDevices).ThenInclude(d => d.Alias))
   .AsQueryable();
```

Error:

> The expression 'd.Alias' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation,
> since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To
> target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t =>
> ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as
> Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by
> composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take
> operations. For more information on including related data, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

```
[
{
    "id": 102,
    "workstation": "workstationName",
    "comments": [],
    "devices": [
        {
            "id": 93524,
            "alias": "xxx",
            "workstation": {
                "id": 102,
                "workstation": "workstationName",
```

Comment: Inside `this.context` do you have something for `TDevices`? How is your database structured? Does Devices have its own table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Include` is designed to return all data for the entity, also it initializes automatically all related properties which are already loaded. So just use fully custom projection instead.

```cs
var workstations = 
   from w this.context.TWorkstations 
   select new 
   {
      w.Id,
      workstation = w.workstationName
      devices = w.TDevices.Select(d => d.Alias).ToArray()
   };
```